# how to select count with a difference condition in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have this database structure

```
table tools     table details
-----------     -------------
id *            id *
name            balance_shoot
                tool_id
```

I need to get count of `tools` that has balance_shoot in `tool_details` that is lesser than or equal zero (danger) and more than a zero (save). something like :

```
[ 
  danger_count => 0,
  save_count   => 5
];
```

I already achieve this:

```
public function index(Request $request){
    $trans_date = date('Y-m-d');

    $tools = Tool::select('id')
    ->whereHas(
        'details' , function ($query) use ($trans_date){
            $query->where('trans_date', $trans_date );
        }
    )
    /*->with([
        'details' => function ($query) use ($trans_date){
            $query->where('trans_date', $trans_date );
        }
    ])*/
    ->withCount([
        'details as danger' => function ($query) use ($trans_date){
            $query->where('trans_date', $trans_date )->where('balance_shoot', '<=', 0 );
        },      

        'details as save' => function ($query) use ($trans_date){
            $query->where('trans_date', $trans_date )
            ->where('balance_shoot', '>', 0 );
        },
    ]);

    return $tools->get();

}
```

And it's return this :

```
 "tools": [
    {
        "id": 101,
        "danger_count": "0",
        "save_count": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": 102,
        "danger_count": "0",
        "save_count": "1"
    }
 ];
```

How can I get that data structure but in one single result return ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> SQL Query

```
select count(*) total, sum(case when balance_shoot < '0' then 1 else 0 end) danger, sum(case when balance_shoot > '0' then 1 else 0 end) safe from tool_dtl group by tool_id
```

> In Laravel you can try this

```
<?php 
$toolDtl = Detail::select(
    array(
        DB::raw('COUNT(*) as total'),
        DB::raw("SUM(CASE 
            WHEN balance_shoot < '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS danger"),
        DB::raw("SUM(CASE
            WHEN balance_shoot > '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS save")
    )
)
->groupBy('tool_id')
->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
?>
```

Comment: thank you. you guide me to the right directions. except I just don't need the groupBy clause

Answer (score 0):

We can count directly using conditional `SUM`

```
Detail::select([
        DB::raw('COUNT(*) as total'),
        DB::raw("SUM(balance_shoot < '0') AS danger"),
        DB::raw("SUM(balance_shoot > '0') AS save")
])
```